# Как связать вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение

Как связать вопрос [A](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121433/private-module-%D0%B2-python), с вопросом [B](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420987/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-init-py/1121453)?

Comment: Так B - это не вопрос, а ответ.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik поправил ссыль

Comment: Ок. Что значит "связать"? Если вопросы похожи, их нужно закрывать как дубликат. Есть ещё механизм объединения, но он не подходит для этого случая.

Comment: Они не одинаковы, но в одном следует дать ссылку на другой

Comment: Ну так дайте эту самую ссылку. Синтаксис `[текст](ссылка)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы вопрос появился в блоке Связанные, надо дать на него ссылку в вопросе или ответе, или даже в комментарии к чему-то из них. При этом образуется двухсторонняя связь.

Если вопросы одинаковы, то можно закрыть один из них как дубликат другого.

Если вопросы прям совсем одинаковы, то можно попросить модератора объединить их - при этом ответы и комментарии из одного вопроса будут перенесены во второй, а первый будет удалён (вроде, без возможности восстановления).